# Error - regarding memory while installing ionic using npm on windows

Tags: memory, ionic-framework, npm, out-of-memory

I am trying to install ionic and cordova on my windows machine OS version - windows 7.
Cordova successfully get installed using

```
npm install -g cordova
```

But when I am trying to install ionic using

```
npm install -g ionic
```

I am getting error:-

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory
```

So I tried one lower version using command

```
npm install -g ionic@1.5
```

So it get installed but it is showing **module source is not supported please upgrade your ionic version**

My node version is **6.3.1**

So can any one help me to install ionic in using npm my windows machine.
or Is there any alternate option to install second last version of ionic or how to solve error of memory for latest ionic version

Comment: initially  i was trying to install in c drive.  and now i tried installation  in d drive so it get installed latest version. so may be beacuse of memory issue problem has occured.